# How we will enable front-end validation based on the xml in validation.xml?

Tags: struts2

i want to know that How we will enable front-end validation based on the xml in validation.xml?

Comment: Learn to clearly construct your questions!

Comment: Do yourself a favour, get a good Struts 2 book, and try to read that first. Or still better learn simple JSP and Servlet first. I am noticing that you are opening lots of thread around, which doesn't really make sense. Nobody will teach you the framework or technology here. Understand the purpose of the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using one of the themes that supports front-end validation (like css_xhtml), you should just have to set validate="true" on your  tag.  That should generate the javascript function from your validation.xml (or ActionName-validation.xml) and call it in an onSubmit handler.